# Save modified xml into internal storage Android

Tags: java, android, xml, nullpointerexception, savechanges

I added node in a existing xml file located in `/data/data.my.package.app/files/file.xml` and I just want to save the file but I didn't find out.

I tried this function seen in an other post :

```
private void save(Document newDoc) throws Exception{
    Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/file.xml"));
    Source source = new DOMSource(newDoc);
    transformer.transform(source, result);
}
```

But I get an null pointer exception on `tranformer.transform()` ... This is how I initialise my Document file.

```
FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/file.xml");
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(is);
```

Thanks a lot for the help
A.D

Comment: do you have write privileges?

Comment: @gmetax Yes I have

Answer (score 1):

The file cannot be new.
Must be already present:

```
StreamResult result = 
     new StreamResult(new File(context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() +   "/file.xml"));
```

for me this work:

```
//save the doc as string  in a text file with the same name (extension   .xml)
save(this, body, dir, FILENAME_XML);

//apply the transformer
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory_p.newTransformer();
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(
    new File(dir+File.separator+FILENAME_XML));
transformer.transform(source, result);
```

the file xml is produced.